# How can an ionic bond have partial covalent in character?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds

I was going through the topic of 'ionic bond' and read this:

> No bond is 100% ionic in character. It has some percentage of covalent character.

I didn't understand how an ionic bond can be partially covalent in character. Please explain along with an example.

Answer (score -1):

One way is **Polarization**. When a small cation approaches a large  anion it distorts the charge density towards itself thereby forming a type of bond which has directional characteristic i.e from ** (-) ----> (+) ** which is characteristic of a **covalent bond**.

This polarization has some rules given by **Fajan **

1. Smaller the cation better distortion/polarization.
2. More the amount of positive charge more is the polarization.
3. **or** more the **charge : radius** ratio of cation more is the polarization.

So in short every cation has the power of polarization and therefore no bond is 100% ionic.